# How to escape square brackets in org-mode table?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I try to export a table to ODT file, but it always interoperates the "[]" as footnote.

My table:

```
| d[4] | 10 | some description |
```

how could I escape the square bracket when export to ODT file?

I tried:

```
| =d[4]= | 10 | some description |
```

It does escape, but it uses different font for "d[4]" which is not what I expected.

**UPDATE**
This is fixed @release_8.3.4-1041-g610ec9 (maybe even early commit).

Comment: Is disabling *all* footnotes an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, that's not a option. Because I use footnote somewhere else.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I cannot reproduce it with current org: Org-mode version 8.3.4 (release_8.3.4-1026-gf0ff25 @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/)

Comment: @Nick It is fixed on release_8.3.4-1041-g610ec9. I haven't check other versions.